# installing lets encrypt SSL in vesta cp

Tags: ssl, digital-ocean, lets-encrypt, vesta

trying to install let's encrypt ssl with vesta cp.

following python-certbot-apache installation path.

it is failing with below error.

Unable to find a virtual host listening on port 80 which is currently needed for Certbot to prove to the CA that you control your domain. Please add a virtual host for port 80.

**UPDATE**

after debugging it is found that vesta cp nginx running at 80 and passing proxy_pass to apache on 8080.

Answer (score 0):

I followed vesta solution from their forum.

1. Check /etc/hostname to see what is your hostname. It should be your domain name.
2. Install ssl , In SSH, as root, run:

> v-add-letsencrypt-domain 'admin' $HOSTNAME '' 'yes'
>
> `(change 'admin' if your hostname domain is not under 'admin' account)`

NOTE: if you need ssl for both www and non-www domains please use
below command

> v-add-letsencrypt-domain 'admin' 'yourdomain.com' 'www.yourdomain.com'
>   'yes'

3. Now in SSH do the follwing:

> v-update-host-certificate admin $HOSTNAME

4. And finally run:

> echo "UPDATE_HOSTNAME_SSL='yes'" >> /usr/local/vesta/conf/vesta.conf